# date picker selected date not selecting

Tags: php, jquery, html

im having a hard time in inserting the selected date date in date picker
when im selecting earlier year the value that inserting to my data base is the current date

heres my code

```
bdate


<link href="jqueryui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

              changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-50:-1",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: '01-01-1950'

        });
        });

</script>
<style>
/*datepicker hack*/
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; } 
</style>



<tr>
    <td>Birthday*</td>
    <td><input id="datepicker" name="bdate" <?php if(isset($bdate)){ echo 'value="'.$bdate.'"';}?> /></td>
  </tr>
```

thanks

Comment: What kind of value is the column in your database set to.

Comment: this is tagged mysql and you talk about database insert, but I see no mysql code... sorry can't help much without knowing what you are currently doing. Please post code in question along with current code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bSVcU/

Answer (score 0):

The default date is in the wrong format, it should be `yy-mm-dd`, so you should have it set to `50-01-01`.

Also the earliest year that datepicker will go to is 1963.